# Parse XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

Hello I want to know how can I parse this simple XML file content in C#. I can have multiple "in"  elements, and from those I want to use date, min, max and state child values.

```
<out>
<in>
<id>16769</id>
<date>29-10-2010</date>
<now>12</now>
<min>12</min>
<max>23</max>
<state>2</state>
<description>enter text</description>
</in>

<in>
<id>7655</id>
<date>12-10-2010</date>
<now>1</now>
<min>1</min>
<max>2</max>
<state>0</state>
<description>enter text</description>
</in>
</out>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [System.XML namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) has all sorts of tools for parsing, reading, and writing XML data. By the way, your XML isn't well-formed; you've got two `<out>` elements, but only one `</out>` element.

Answer (score 2):

Linq to xml is also helpful for parsing xml -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Also - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb308960.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need [System.XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.aspx), starting with [XmlDocument.Load(filename)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx).

Once you have the `XmlDocument` loaded, you can drill down into it as needed using the built-in .Net XML object model, starting from [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) level.  You can walk the tree recursively in a pretty intuitive way, capturing what you want from each [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) as you go.

Alternatively (and preferably) you can quickly locate all `XmlNode`s in your `XmlDocument` that match certain conditions using [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471.aspx) - examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx).  An example of usage in C# is [XmlNode.SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample {

  public static void Main() {

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("booksort.xml");

    XmlNodeList nodeList;
    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

    nodeList=root.SelectNodes("descendant::book[author/last-name='Austen']");

    //Change the price on the books.
    foreach (XmlNode book in nodeList)
    {
      book.LastChild.InnerText="15.95";
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Display the modified XML document....");
    doc.Save(Console.Out);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples can be found here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/readwritexmltutmellli2111282005041517am/readwritexmltutmellli21.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This might be beyond what you want to do, but worth mentioning...

I hate parsing XML. Seriously, I almost refuse to do it, especially since .NET can do it for me. What I would do is create an "In" object that has the properties above. You probably have one already, or it would take 60 seconds to create. You'll also need a List of In objects called "Out".

Then just deserialze the XML into the objects. This takes just a few lines of code. Here is an example. BTW, this makes changing and re-saving the data just as easy.

[How to serialize/deserialize](http://geekswithblogs.net/TimH/archive/2006/02/09/68857.aspx)